# LocalDate to Epoch by Ignoring DayLightSaving

Tags: java, java-8, epoch, localdate, jsonserializer

Business case:

A date wield of dataType `LocalDate` needs to be converted into `epoch`.

```
private LocalDate someDate;
```

Problem I am having is, with day light saving in place sometimes **date is getting converted to n-1**.

**Example:** Date is `28-Feb-2037` is converted into => `27-Feb-2037` which is incorrect.

**Explanation:** When we are converting from LocalDate to Epoch and taking the ZoneId as system default, it takes in consideration the daylight savings. For this reason the epoch is decreasing by 1 hour and when UI again converts it to date it becomes `n-1 date 23:00:00 hrs`.

My conversion code looks like this

```
someDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond() * 1000); //systemDefault = EUROPE/PARIS
```

How to ignore Daylight-Savings while conversion?

Comment: Do you want to keep the system zone id but ignore daylight saving?

Comment: @EugenCovaci Yes.

Comment: I suspect that you are seeking the wrong solution to your problem. While using offset +01:00 instead of time zone Europe/Paris will solve the problem if the client time zone is at offset +01:00, the problem will persist for clients at offset +00:00, -01:00, etc. Also I’m confused because I don’t think anyone knows yet whether Europe/Paris will be at offset +01:00 or +02:00 in the winter of 2037 (my Java 11 thinks +01:00).

Comment: I searched for information about the future of time in France. This is about the EU: [E.U. Votes to End Mandatory Switch to Daylight Saving Time](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/27/world/europe/daylight-savings-time-european-union.html). It seems the French are in favour of permanent standard time, that is, +01:00: [59,17% ont dit préférer rester à l'heure d'été qu'à l'heure d'hiver.](https://www.linternaute.fr/actualite/guide-vie-quotidienne/1038385-changement-d-heure-la-france-a-lheure-d-ete-2020-toutes-les-questions/#vote-sur-le-changement-d-heure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Ignoring timezone below code will do the job for you

```
localDate.atStartOfDay().atOffset(UTC).toEpochSecond()
```

Or Maybe you need this:

```
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1");// Paris timezone without daylight saving
    localDate.atStartOfDay(timeZone.toZoneId()).toEpochSecond();
```

The idea is to use a fixed zone offset to get rid of daylight saving.

Comment: Shorter and less generated garbage to use `localDate.toEpochSecond(LocalTime.MIN, ZoneOffset.UTC)` *(Java 9+)*

Comment: Default TimeZone is Europe/Paris for me. Is it okay to change that to UTC?

Comment: @KunalVohra It's a *date-only*, it has no time zone. Time zones only applies when time-of-day in involved.

Comment: @Andreas , with that what is wromg with code that I have put in question. It is again just date there and no time? Can you explain your answer a bit for me.

Comment: @KunalVohra No, it's not. So you want to keep the system zone id but ignore daylight saving. I will modify the answer.

Comment: @KunalVohra Calling `atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())` applied an offset. E.g. if you are in a +02:00 time zone, then `2020-01-05` becomes `2020-01-05 00:00 +02:00`, which means `2020-01-04 22:00 UTC`, which as you can see is the wrong date value. Remember, epoch times that include a time-of-day (e.g. epoch seconds) is always in UTC.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. Please update. It will be great help :)

Comment: @KunalVohra Please update what? This is not my answer. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62788015/5221149) doesn't apply a time zone at all, so this entire conversion doesn't apply to it.

Comment: I recommend you keep fingers off the `TimeZone` class, it⁄s poorly designed and long outdated. Just pass `ZoneOffset.ofHours(1)` to `atStartOfDay()`.

Comment: Thanks @OleV.v. for your comments on question.

Answer (score 1):

> LocalDate needs to be converted into epoch

**Call [`toEpochDay()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toEpochDay--)** to get epoch *days* since Jan 1, 1970.

Multiply by `86400` if you need epoch *seconds* (aka [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)).

Multiply by `86400000` if you need epoch *milliseconds* (common in Java).